# Manually verify firebase otp

Tags: android, firebase, one-time-password

i am looking for a way to find which code is sent to me from firebase phone authentication because i want to manually verify that code.Now the problem is firebase is autometically detecting the sms and onVerificationCompleted() is called but i have a button and i want to manually enter otp code and verify.Below is my code.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phonenumber,
                120,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                this, new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(PhoneVerification.this, PictureActivity.class);
                Log.e("iamhere","Credential  IS"+phoneAuthCredential);
                intent.putExtra("email",email);
                intent.putExtra("phoneNumber",phonenumber);
                intent.putExtra("password",password);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(PhoneVerification.this, "Please fill the registration form", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
                Toast.makeText(PhoneVerification.this, "Failed: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
                Toast.makeText(PhoneVerification.this, "Check your phone for verification code", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                String mVerificationId = s;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I think this is the only way to verify. But why you are looking to verify manually

Comment: Lets say if i have entered a mobile number and that sim card is in another mobile in that case it cannot automatically verify code and i have to enter that code manually

Comment: Dont you get an option to verify it manually by entering the code manually

Comment: I dont have any string code which i can check if its equal to entered code

Answer (score 0):

In case if code does not get detected automatically, the user has to manually enter it through EditText

```
    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String txt = otpEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                if (txt.isEmpty() || txt.length() < 6) {
                    otp.setError("Enter valid code");

                    return;
                }

                //verifying the code entered manually
                if (isOnline()) {
                    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, txt);

                    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
                } else {
                    showSnack(relativeLayout, "Unable to connect! Check internet connection");
                }
            }
        });



private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(Verification.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        //verification successfull do next task
                    } else {

                        //verification unsuccessful.. display an error message


                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            Toast.makeText(Verification.this, "Incorrect OTP entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Verification.this, "Unable to verify please retry later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        }


                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Here is the auto verification:

```
 private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

        //Getting the code sent by SMS
        String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();

        //sometime the code is not detected automatically
        //in this case the code will be null
        //so user has to manually enter the code
        if (code != null) {
            otpEditText.setText(code);
            //verifying the code
            verifyVerificationCode(code);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
        FancyToast.makeText(Verification.this, e.getMessage(), FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG, FancyToast.CONFUSING, false).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

        //storing the verification id that is sent to the user
        mVerificationId = s;
    }
};
```

Check out the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) for more info.

Comment: Please fix the code indenting - it looks quite ugly. And the documentation you've linked to is possibly a Google search result which redirects to an incorrect link. (EDIT: I've helped to fix the link, but please consider pasting the direct link.)

Comment: what if the user is already signed in, or he is still signing up?